# Magento - Create a minimum shipping charge

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, magento

We use USPS API for international shipping.  The API returns a shipping cost and we add % Handling charge.  We want to set a minimum charge, e.g., if shipping + handling is less than $5 we want to set the shipping price to $5.  Would this require writing a full shipping module or just adapt the USPS module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by overriding just a portion of the USPS module. The method that applies handling is in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`:

```
public function getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost)
```

To override this method for US, create a new model override on `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps` (see elsewhere for how to set up this override):

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps extends Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps {

    function getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost) {
        $parentValue = parent::getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost);
        return max($parentValue,5);
    }
}
```

This will implement a "floor" for shipping prices. Keep in mind that this may in some cases lead to results that users notice as being odd. For contrived example:

- First Class - $5.00
- Media Mail - $5.00
- Priority Mail - $5.33

Keep it aboveboard and let them know that you're doing this.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe